# "under any name" meaning in the sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> ***Under any name***, King mesmerizes the reader.

I didn't find the phrase in my dictionary. What does it mean in the sentence?

Comment: You need a better dictionary. [Longman definition of under](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/under): if you write or do something under a particular name, you do it using that name instead of your real name  *He made a few records under the name of Joe Ritchie.*

Comment: @ColleenV I see, thanks for the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without context, but it's probably literal. Some authors use a pseudonym, i.e. a fake name. If it's talking about Stephen King, he published some of his books under the pseudonym "Richard Bachman". So the writer here is saying that whatever name the author uses, whether "Stephen King" or "Richard Bachman" (or if he's talking about some other writer named King, whatever names that writer uses), he still "mesmerizes the reader".

Comment: Yeah, it's talking about Stephen King.  The sentence is someone wrote on the backside of his book.

Comment: @dan  You should probably avoid the word *backside*, because it has [other, more common meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/backside)!  Just say "on the back of the book."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Yes, but I'm not sure what that has to do with any of the issues at hand.